# Multi-thread MergeSort

Tags: java, multithreading, merge, java-8, mergesort

I would like to realise a mergesort with multithreading.

so here is my code :

```
public class MergeSort<E extends Comparable<T>> implements Runnable {

public void run() {
    mergeSort(array);
}

public synchronized void mergeSort(List<E> array) {     
    int size = array.size();
    if (size > 1){
        int mid = size / 2;
        List<T> l  = array.subList(0,mid);
        List<T> r = array.subList(mid,vec.size());
        Thread t = new Thread(new MergeSort<E>(left));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MergeSort<E>(right));
        t.start();
        t2.start();
        merge(l, r, array);
    }
}
```

I would like my MergeSort to run, create 2 new threads, and then the method call the merge and finishes his job.
I tried without thread, juste by calling Mergesort(left)... It worked, so my algorithm is correct, but when I try with threads, the List is not sorted.

So, how to synchronize the threads? I Know there will be too much threads, but I just want to know how to synchronize to sort the list.

Comment: The `synchronized` modifier is useless. Since each thread uses a different instance of your `MergeSort` class, it has no effect. (If it had, it rendered your multi-threading useless). But your code lacks any working synchronization, i.e. you are not waiting for the completion of the asynchronous actions, before trying to merge the results.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly because some of the code is missing, but it does look like you're calling mergesort with "left" twice.

Comment: I Modified it, it was a typo !

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to keep in mind:

1. Just by creating thread, dont assume that thread would start running instanteneously.
2. You are injecting left as parameter to both your thread instead of l and r.
3. If at all you want it to work, you would need thread pair each one to do its task and once that is done, you could proceed with next two halves after merging the result.

Comment: How can I do that? I saw the .join() method, but i don't know how to use it, when I call it, I have this :  Unhandled exception type InterruptedException